# Vague 500 error trying to register PYPI

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I am getting a 500 internal server error while trying to register or upload to PYPI.

```
$ python setup.py register --show-response

-- snip --

running check
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
1. use your existing login,
2. register as a new user,
3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:

Username: sambev
Password:
Registering reportermd to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Server response (500): Internal Server Error
```

The package is there: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/reportermd
But I can't use pip or easy_install to install it. (Neither can find it)

Also, I can login through the site and use the package submit form and upload my PKG-INFO file, but I get the same generic 500 error.

Any ideas on what might be wrong or how to debug this?

Source code here: https://github.com/sambev/reportermd

**UPDATE**: It looks like it must have been something with PyPI at the time. It seems to be working now. Although I have to admit that was a pretty frustrating and confusing experience.

Comment: From my past experience with my own websites, I get 500 errors when there's an error on the server, so this seems to me like it's PyPi's problem. Not totally sure about that, but that's my best guess. If this is the case, that also means you won't be able to fix it.

Comment: Yeah.  I figured with a 500 it's an error on the server but https://status.python.org makes it seem like everything is fine.  I guess I am worried that it is a weird problem with my package? I'll keep trying...

Comment: Is the source for your package available somewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this was a temporary problem caused due to a server issue (http code: 500) on pypi servers.

Answer (score 0):

Make **.pypirc** file in you $HOME and update as

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
repository= https://www.python.org/pypi
username=your_username
password=you_password
```

Register: `python setup.py register -r pypi`

Upload sdist: `python setup.py sdist upload -r pypi`

Upload bdist: `python setup.py bdist upload -r pypi`